# WSO2 ESB adds default namespace in xslt

Tags: xslt, soap, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and I want to modify soap message using xslt.

My soap message:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nis.ayss.com.tr/">
         <return>
            <result>true</result>
            <responseList>
               <name>STACK</name>
               <number>001</number>
            </responseList>
         </return>
      </ns2:getResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I want to change "name" element to "brand" and modify this message like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nis.ayss.com.tr/">
         <return>
            <result>true</result>
            <responseList>
               <brand>STACK</brand>
               <number>001</number>
            </responseList>
         </return>
      </ns2:getResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns2="http://nis.ayss.com.tr/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <brand>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </brand>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I created an xslt file as a local entry in WSO2 ESB. But it adds a default namespace as xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" and changes xslt as:

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <brand xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </brand>
</xsl:template>
```

So my result soap messsage is:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nis.ayss.com.tr/">
         <return>
            <result>true</result>
            <responseList>
               <brand xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">STACK</brand>
               <number>001</number>
            </responseList>
         </return>
      </ns2:getResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

How can I modify this element name without adding a namespace using XSLT in WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XSL local entry, replace the "brand" tag with a xsl:element

```
 <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:element name="brand">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```